# How to copy NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I create a mutable array in main.m and place 3 objects in it. I know they are there as I can manipulate them in main.m. I want to be able to use this array in a class I have created. Here is a portion of the code I've done.
//main.m

```
#import "Portfolio.h"

NSMutableArray *holdings = [NSMutableArray array];
[holdings addObject:stock1];
[holdings addObject:stock2];
[holdings addObject:stock3];
```

//Portfolio.h
    #import

```
@interface Portfolio : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *holdings;
}
-(void) totalValue;

@end
```

//Portfolio.m
    #import "Portfolio.h"

```
@implementation Portfolio

-(void) totalValue {
    NSArray *copyHoldings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: holdings];
    NSLog(@"%@", copyHoldings);
}

@end
```

The NSLog command in totalValue prints nothing, just two parenthesis. Is this not possible?

Note, I know I really should somehow use the array I created in main.m but I cannot figure out how to refer to it and then use it.

Thanks!
Keith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem: you have two variables with the same name `holdings`: one in main.m , and the other one in `Portfolio`. When you call

```
NSArray *copyHoldings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: holdings];
```

You're actually referring to the `holdings` Portfolio instance variable, which was not initialized, and that's why it prints nothing.

Second problem: after you fix the name collision issue above, you need to expose your global variable from main.m:

```
// Put it at the top of Portfolio.m, outside of class implementation
extern NSMutableArray* holdingsFromMain;
```

While the above should fix your problem, I would strongly advocate against using global variables...

Comment: I got it to work using your answer - thank you! Odd, but I didn't use the extern line. Again, thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you're not initializing a new `Portfolio` object and setting the array on it.

main.m:

```
// ..

NSMutableArray *holdings = [NSMutableArray array];
[holdings addObject:stock1];
[holdings addObject:stock2];
[holdings addObject:stock3];

Portfolio *portfolio = [[Portfolio alloc] init];
porforlio.holdings = holdings;

[portfolio totalValue]; // should print
```

Comment: Portfolio *total = [[Portfolio alloc] init];
        [total totalValue];
Sorry, I should have included the above two lines in main.m.

Comment: So are you setting `porforlio.holdings`?  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, but I still have the same issue, nothing prints when I call totalValue, just empty parenthesis.